# invoke non static method by name

Tags: c#, .net, methods, static, instance

I've been trying to invoke a method by name but the problem is the method I invoke cannot be static and it needs to be of the current class.

I've tried the way of doing it like this:

```
public static void InvokeMenuMethod(string methodName, object sender, EventArgs e)
  Type calledType = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass");
  calledType.InvokeMember(
    methodName,
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
    null,
    null,
    new object[] { sender, e }
  );
}
```

This obviously only works for static members so I tried something like this

```
public static void InvokeMenuMethod(string methodName, object sender, EventArgs e)
  Type calledType = Type.GetType("this");
  calledType.InvokeMember(
    methodName,
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public,
    null,
    null,
    new object[] { sender, e }
  );
}
```

But I get `Must specify binding flags describing the invoke operation required (BindingFlags.InvokeMethod CreateInstance GetField SetField GetProperty SetProperty).
Parameter name: bindingFlags` error...

So how can I go about doing this?

**EDIT:**

So:

```
public void InvokeMenuMethod(string methodName, object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Type.GetType("this").InvokeMember(
        methodName,
        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null,
        this,
        new object[] { sender, e }
    );
}
```

Gives a `NullReferenceException`

**Solution:**
No "this" in `Type.GetType("this")`

Comment: Have you tried `BindingFlags.Instance`?

Comment: please see my changed code - GetType("this") is giving you the exception because it is wrong...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try

```
 this.GetType().InvokeMember(
    methodName,
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null,
    this,
    new object[] { sender, e }
  );
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3dhzwy.aspx)

> If InvokeMethod is specified by itself, BindingFlags.Public,
>   BindingFlags.Instance, and BindingFlags.Static are automatically
>   included

Comment: That's `BindingFlags.Default`.  Once you specify any `BindingFlags`, you lose the default.

Comment: @SLaks the above is copy&pasted from MSDN - it says that specifying `InveokeMethod` by itself includes the other flags, check the link out...

Answer (score 0):

You can add `BingingFlags.Instance`.

Comment: You mean `BindingFlags.Instance`?